# Looking for experimental data for titration curves

Tags: acid-base, titration, reference-request, databases

I am looking for real, open source and free **experimental dataset** (not image, scan of table) of acid/base titration curves: pH versus titrant volume for many combination (strong/weak acid/base, polyprotic acids, etc.).

I could not find something satisfactory over the internet. Where could I find this kind of dataset?

Comment: Sorry. My answer did really seem unattuned to the question. But I liked looking at the curves!

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is papers. Look up titrations in Google Scholar and then use open databases to download the paper itself, such as Library Genesis.